# What is the program responsible for rendering the images of the desktop background?

Tags: windows-7, windows, regedit

I'm trying to find the program responsible for the images on the windows 7 desktop background. I know that it used to be `explorer.exe` but when I restarted that, the image cycling software did not reboot.

I'm trying to get it to shuffle images faster than 10 seconds and I have already modified the interval in `regedit.exe` but it won't accept the new amount of milliseconds that I specified.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Windows Explorer on Windows 7 and File Explorer on more modern versions of Windows.  If Windows Explorer isn’t running then there isn’t a desktop.

Comment: Set the time you want in the registry. Then set your slideshow ignoring the Interval box. If you don't click the Interval box then it does not update the registry. However changing the slideshow does make it **read** the interval from the registry.